# Search in ListView populated with JSON data

Tags: android, json, listview, search

My problem is the following: i want to implement a search mechanism into my JSON-data generated ListView, but i don't know what to do in my case.

I've found a lot of examples but i want to implement the simplest solution possible and, especially, an understandable one.

Here's my Pastebin with the Adapter and the MainActivity class.

http://pastebin.com/SSXHXK7m

Can you give me any suggestion? I'm stuck.

Comment: Does it need to remain in json? There are a number of libraries out there that give you data that is easier to work with. Outside of that `simplest` and `understandable` are relative terms.

Comment: Hi, yes, they need to remain in JSON, because i'm sending the data via POST (PHP page) directly to a JSON file and, then, the JSON sends the data to the app. The other option in my case can only be XML. Yeah, simplest and understandable are related to two things: The first one is that i need only to search with an EditView and nothing more, the "understandable" means that possibly i don't want a link with someone pasting code and saying "this is the solution to my problem" but i can't understand it in my case.

Comment: I would personally recommend looking into GSON (I would say Volley, but it sounds like you have your networking built and it may not be worth rebuilding it). GSON will let you convert your JSON to objects (and vice versa) making it easier to work with. Once you have done that searching may be simpler since manual parsing won't really be necessary.

Comment: And what about the manual parsing? In the meanwhile i'll search Volley, but, as you said, if it's only a meaning of some lines of code, i think that finding a solution for this particular situation would be the best way (i don't want to study another library right now if it's not strictly necessary)

Comment: Well I mean all you really need to do is create an editable text that you can search with (EditText or SearchView). On submit, have a method that parses your json for matches with your search query, creates a list out of those matches, sets your adapter to that list, and notifies that adapter there has been a change using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). I would make that search an AsyncTask so you can easily manage a progress bar if you need to and you won't freeze up your main UI thread.

Comment: Can you provide me a really basic example based on my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search functionality would be something like this

```
public void searchList(String query){
    List<Records> matchedActors = new ArrayList<Records>();
    for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
        if(adapter.getItem(i).getAuthor().equals(query)
            matchedActors.add(adapter.getItem(i));
    }

    // See below for what to put here
}
```

You can then either modify the adapter by creating/calling a method in your adapter class that is something like

```
public void modifyList(List<Records> actorList){
    this.actorList = actorList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call `adapter.modifyList(matchedActors)` after your search, or by instantiating a new instance of your adapter after your serach via,

```
adapter = new RecordsAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout."your_layout_resource", actorList);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**EDIT**

I didn't notice you were using a Filterable ArrayAdapter :P You can implement the following funcitionality in your adapter.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {


     @Override
     protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
         actorList = (List<Records>) results.values;
         notifyDataSetChanged(); 
     }

     @Override
     protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
         FilterResults results = new FilterResults(); 
         List<Records> matchedActors = new ArrayList<Records>();

         //NOTE mOriginalValues will be a class variable we use to keep track of our values
         if (mOriginalValues == null) {
             mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Records>(actorList); 
         }

         if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) { 
             results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
             results.values = mOriginalValues;
         } 
         else {
             constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
             List<Records> matchedActors = new ArrayList<Records>();
             for(int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++){
                if(mOriginalValues.getAuthor().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint)
                    matchedActors.add(getItem(i);
             }

             // set the Filtered result to return
             results.count = matchedActors.size();
             results.values = matchedActors;
         }
         return results;
     }

     return filter;
 }
```

Comment: or you could use the already provided `Filter` mechanism in ArrayAdapter

Comment: @njzk2 I don't know why I thought he was using a different type of adapter. Now that I see that I will rework the code. Thanks

Comment: Something is wrong with the Edit one: i'm getting some errors. Seems that a parenthesis misses a semicolumn. I have to declare mOriginalValues as a class variable, but which kind of variable is it? In the publishResults method, isn't that actorList the ArrayList records declared in the beginning of the class? This import (import android.widget.Filter.FilterResults;) is not available and matchedActors is not found. What is it? and where should i declare "adapter"? As an ArrayAdapter something at the beginning of the class (Adapter)? Sorry for these really newbie questions :)

Comment: @dabadee I am going to talk you through this because simply answering it won't help you understand what you are doing: 1. If it says you need a semicolon, try adding it and see what it does. 2. Look at what we are trying to set mOriginalValues to, seeing that and seeing that we will want to access mOriginalValues throughout our class, how might you declare the variable to match this? 3. That import should be available, it is part of Android's framework. 4. You are the one that created the variable matchedActors, you should know what it is :)

Comment: Ok, the semicolumn problem is avoided, but the import problem still remains (The type android.widget.Filter.FilterResults is not visible), i don't know why, but in some Stack questions i've found that this problem is not only mine. Is not that method "public", or does it mean something else? mOriginalValues is initially an ArrayList reference to Records class, isn't it? And finally, the adapter that you are referring to "adapter.getItem[i]" what is it? If i'm not doing wrongly, i'm writing this function inside the Adapter class itself

Comment: @dabadee sorry I didn't realize that isn't an import you need to explicitly declare, it should be handled by `import android.widget.Filter;`. If it isn't, something is scoped wrong. You are correct, mOriginalValues is initially an array list of records, thus `ArrayList<Records>`. Lastly, sorry, I quickly wrote it up, if you are in your adapter, you can remove `adapter.` and just call `getItem(i)`. That will return the item (i) from your list. Since you are using a list of records, getItem(i) will return the record in position i of the list.